# State Monad Bind

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, state-monad

I think I understand how the State Monad works. I've managed to write some code which uses the State Monad.

I understand how the Monad instance of State works:

```
instance Monad (State s) where  
return x = State $ \s -> (x,s)  
(State h) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s  
                                    (State g) = f a  
                                in  g newState
```

This code works perfectly fine:

```
type PeopleStack = [String]

enterClub :: String -> State PeopleStack String
enterClub name = state $ \xs -> (name ++ " entered club", name:xs)

leaveClub :: State PeopleStack String
leaveClub = state $ \(x:xs) -> ("Someone left the club", xs)

clubAction :: State PeopleStack String
clubAction = do
  enterClub "Jose"
  enterClub "Thais"
  leaveClub
  enterClub "Manuel"
```

However when I try to write clubAction in a bind function I can't seem to get it working.

this is what I have tried:

```
let statefulComputation1 = enterClub "Jose"
statefulComputation1 :: State PeopleStack String

runState (statefulComputation1 >>= (enterClub "Manuel") >>= leaveClub) []
```

I get this error:

```
<interactive>:13:22:
Couldn't match type ‘StateT
                       PeopleStack Data.Functor.Identity.Identity String’
               with ‘String
                     -> StateT PeopleStack Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a’
Expected type: String
               -> StateT PeopleStack Data.Functor.Identity.Identity a
  Actual type: State PeopleStack String
Relevant bindings include
  it :: (a, PeopleStack) (bound at <interactive>:13:1)
In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘leaveClub’
In the first argument of ‘runState’, namely
  ‘(state1 >>= leaveClub)’
```

My question is how do I translate that do notation to a function using bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `(>>)` instead of `(>>=)`:

```
runState (statefulComputation1 >> (enterClub "Manuel") >> leaveClub) []
```

`(enterClub "Manuel")` has type `State PeopleStack String` while `(>>=)` requires a function `String -> State PeopleStack a` as its second argument. Since you don't use use the result from `statefulComputation1` you can combine them with `(>>)` which ignores the result from the first state computation.

Comment: ok. so I can use >> and then just partially apply (enterClub "Manuel")? thats whats happening right?

Comment: @JoseMariaLanda - `enterClub` only has one parameter so `enterClub "Manuel"` isn't a partial application. But yes, if you have two `State` values you want to run in sequence and you only need the effects of the first you can use `>>`. If you need the result from the first you use `>>=` to construct the following state actions.

Answer (score 2):

Each item on the right side of the bind operator (>>=) needs to be a lambda...., so this would work

```
runState (statefulComputation1 >>= \_ -> enterClub "Manuel" >>= \_ -> leaveClub) []
```

or, you can use the shorthand `(>>)`

```
runState (statefulComputation1 >> enterClub "Manuel" >> leaveClub) []
```

Comment: oh ok. Its that since State Int Int is the same as \s -> (Int, Int) I thought that was the function that was consuming the stateful operation. So it has to be: ( \ _ -> s -> (a,s)) instead right?

Comment: Pretty much, except it's not quite "the same as," it's wrapped up in a newtype.  But yes.